# How can I import historical Google Analytics data into Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I've migrated an Android app from Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics. The Firebase Analytics console shows data from the time I migrated. But it does not show any of the historical data which is still in Google Analytics.

How can I import this historical Google Analytics data, so everything shows up in Firebase Analytics?

Comment: I seriously doubt you can.  Have you checked the documentation? What does it say?

Comment: I've spent a day researching / asking fellow developers but we can't find any documentation on this, hence hoping someone from Stackoverflow might help. I had expected it would happen automatically, but it didn't.

Comment: Why would you doubt it? It would be a better UI experience to have all the data (historical and present) in 1 console, not spread over 2 consoles. And I've heard from other developers that their historical data has been imported into Firebase Analytics, but none can remember how they did it.

Comment: Like @DaImTo I am pretty positive that it's impossible. The data models and analytics mechanisms of the 2 services are too different to allow a seamless / automatic migration.

Comment: @Sébastien if it is please answer the question it would be nice to know how its done for future reference.   Thanks.

Comment: Any solution on this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no API to import historical data into Firebase Analytics.

If you think this is a feature that many developers might need, you can request it [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: As of now i am converting my app from google analytics to Firebase analytics. How can we migrate my previous GA data to firebase as it is difficult to check two accounts to compare data.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get data from Google Analytics to Firebase is by importing data to Big Query and then merging the data. Big Query lets you perform in depth queries on your data too.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but it's the correct answer. The data models are fundamentally different between GA & Firebase, so integrating the two has to be managed by the developer/analytics team. Otherwise it's apples & oranges.